# Extract data from a two columned listbox to a sheet

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a two-columned listbox, which I've manually added entries to using

```
.AddItem (potato)
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = bananaTbx.Text
```

When the user closes the userform all of the data is lost, so I want to have a save & exit button which saves the data to a sheet.  However, it can't be saved to specific cells as the size of the list is dynamic and they will continually be adding to the master list in the sheet.

I tried to do something like this to extract the data:

```
Dim i As Integer

'loop through each row number in the list
For i = 0 To Userform1.Listbox1.ListCount - 1
    'create sequence 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 ... to reference the current list row
    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(i + 0.5, 0)
    'create sequence 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 ... to reference current column in list
    If Len(CStr(i / 2)) > 1 Then
        k = 0
    Else
        k = 1
        Sheets("Data").Range("A1" & ":" & "A" & i).Value = Userform1.ListBox1.List(j, k)
    End If
```

Error:

```
1004 Object defined error
```

How can I do this properly or in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple userform to demonstrate how to Extract Values / Data from a multi-column Listbox on a Userform

Start by creating a simple userform with a few controls

[image: userform]

add a new `Module1` to your Project and stick the below code in it

```
Sub TestUserForm()
    UserForm1.Show
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

in Project Explorer (VBE) Right-click on the `UserForm1` and hit `View Code`

Copy and paste the below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    With ListBox1
        .AddItem TextBox1.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = TextBox2.Value
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' create a results sheets if you do not already have one
    Set ws = Sheets("Results")

    Dim nextAvailableRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        nextAvailableRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ws.Range("A" & nextAvailableRow) = ListBox1.Column(0, i)
        ws.Range("B" & nextAvailableRow) = ListBox1.Column(1, i)
    Next i

    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Create a new spreadsheet and name it `Results`

Run the `TestUserForm` macro

Add sample data to the list and click `Save` button

[image: result]